# Google Play: Application is not compatible

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, apk, compatibility

I uploaded my apk on Google Play and it is compatible with only kit-kat version.
On other devices it is showing 'Not Compatible' even on Google play developer console, it is showing very less devices compatibility list.

My manifest is, Posting only permissions and uses,

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
```

is there any thing, i am missing? Please suggest me.

Comment: You can goto your app's page using an incompatible device and find out why its incompatible : http://www.ghacks.net/2013/05/06/find-out-why-apps-are-incompatible-with-your-android-device/

Comment: @ShivamVerma I tried but it is not showing the reason behind the incompatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"/>`

This was introduced in API 18 and hence the app will not show up for lower API Versions. There could be other features/permissions too. You should check the min API versions required before using a particular feature/permission.

Ref : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess its because some of the Permissions thats not avaiable on those devices. Just check if all the devices supports the features that you have mentioned in your manifest file.

See [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#market-feature-filtering) as well